# Generate a Flat-Top PAM signal with input as ASCII

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, binary

[image]

I have made the conditions but the output is just a dot. Willing to be corrected. The expected output should be be a Flat top PAM.

```html
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import pi

a = input("Enter a String: ")
b = (f"{ord(i):08b}" for i in a)
c = ("".join(b))
fb = 44100
tb = 1/float(fb)
t= 0.30
N= len(c)
Fs = N
ixL=(-0.5*Fs*tb)
ixR=((N-0.5)*Fs*tb)
tt=np.arange(ixL, ixR)/float(Fs)
st = np.sin(2*pi*fb*tt) 
print(Fs)
print(tb)
print(ixL)
print(c)
print(N)
print(tt)
print(st)
plt.title('Unipolar Binary Flat-Top PAM for String "Test", Fb=100 bits/sec, Fs= 44100 Hz')
plt.plot(st,color='red',marker='*')
plt.ylabel('s(t)')
plt.xlabel('t[sec]')
plt.grid()
```

Comment: what have you tried beyond just copy and pasting your homework problem to stackoverflow?   please make sure to read the FAQ and how to ask :) you will have much better luck at getting an answer ...

Comment: I am sorry it is just my first time using stack overflow. so desperate to get it done.

Comment: @JoranBeasley can you teach me how to make this output a variable? also I am new to programming.
a = "test"
a_bytes = bytes(a, "ascii")
print(' '.join(["{0:b}".format(x) for x in a_bytes]))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.